# Call a function on result of ListView Eval call

Tags: asp.net, html, listview, eval

i have a list view in my pages and i want to display some statistics, my Restaurant class has a Reservations property `public List<Reservation> Reservations { get; private set; }`, in my ListView, i would like to display number of reservations, but without making a new property like "ReservationsCount", nothing like this `<%#Eval("Reservations")%>.Count` doesn´t work

```
<td id="Td10" runat="server">
    <%#Eval("Reservations")%>
</td>
```

Result of this `<%#Eval("Reservations")%>` is in the aspx page considered object, not a list of Restaurants, i don´t really know why, i am just beggining with asp.net so please help, maybe the solution is ridiculously easy:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try applying the `count()` directly after the `Eval()`:

```
<%# ((List<Reservation>)Eval("Reservations")).Count() %>
```

As far as I know you would need to reference `System.Linq` for this to work. Without `Linq` you could try using the `Count` property of `List<T>`:

```
<%# ((List<Reservation>)Eval("Reservations")).Count %>
```

Comment: It doesn´t work either, and i can´t call .Count property, because that Eval function returns type object, not a List<T> :(

Comment: Updated my answer to cast the type.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i´ve edited my question to put there the final code

Comment: You're welcome! I've just rolled back. SO is a Q&A page, so there is a question, and there is an answer. The answer is nothing worth without the question. Or, to say it the other way round: Never answer your question *inside* your question. :-)

Comment: I know, but the code posted in these comments are very confusing, and your answer was helpfull, but doesn´t wrong fully, so i just wated to post it in case others have similar problem:)

Comment: This approach blocks the UI until data for all rows is loaded. Another approach may be to use a DTO get the count populated in it ahead of binding the data to UI. Is there a way to use asp .net Eval asynchronously?